# How to get list of each SVG element under mouse AND change color of each element under mouseenter/touchstart in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/mmmd81/6m0kq19f/48/

I need to pass an array of specified color changes to each SVG element under the mouse while also obtaining the list of elements under it.  On mouseleave/touchend, the elements return to their original state.  (Or they can even return to a single state, as long as they change)

I think I may need to use mouseenter and mouseleave... and touchstart and touchend?

CSS pointer events allow me to obtain the list, but I can't figure out how to pass the array of colors that will move to the next top-most element when the mouseleaves and goes into a new top element.

I'm really stuck on this so any help is appreciated.

```
(function() {
const svg = document.querySelector('#Shapes'),
      output = document.querySelector('#test');

function printElement(elm) {
    var id = elm.id ? ' id="' + elm.id + '"' : "";
    return "<" + elm.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + ">";
}

function hitTest(e) {
    const x = e.clientX,
          y = e.clientY,
          elms = [];

    let elm;
    while(true) {
        elm = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        if(!svg.contains(elm)) {
            break;
        }

        elms.push(elm);
        
        
          //Goal is to pass ARRAY HERE that will color the first element under the mouse red.  Second element under mouse orange 0.2%, etc.  And keep track of number of elements to be able to print/highlight extracted text formatted with HTML with printElement below
        
        //Color 1 redpoint5   -  rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0.5)
        //Color 2 orangepoint2  -  rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.2)
        //Color 3 yellowpoint2  -  rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)
        //Color 4 greenpoint2  -  rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)
        //Color 5 bluepoint2  -  rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)
        //Color 6 indigopoint2  -  rgba(75, 0, 130, 0.2)
        //Color 7 violetpoint2  -  rgba(148, 0, 211, 0.2)
        //Color 8 blackpoint2 -  rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
        //Color 9 blackpoint1  -  rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
        //Color 10 blackpoint01  -  rgba(0,0,0,0.01)

        
//Pass array for each item here.
//Keep track of number of colors used.
//If 3 elements under mouse, text 1 extrapolated to printElement is redpoint5+orangepoint2+yellowpoint2 
//If 5 elements under mouse, text 1 extrapolated to printElement is redpoint5+orangepoint2+yellowpoint2+greenpoint2+bluepoint2

//Would also like to be able to visualize
      
       
   

        
        var orderedcolor = ["rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0.5)", "rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)", " rgba(75, 0, 130, 0.2)", " rgba(148, 0, 211, 0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.01)"];
        
        for(n = 0; n < orderedcolor.length; n++){


  elm.style.fill = orderedcolor[n];     
}


   
   
   
        
        //Hide the element from the next round of `elementFromPoint()`:
        elm.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        
        
    }
        

    output.textContent = elms.map(printElement).join(' ');
```

//Cleanup:  remove fill, then add pointer.
//NEED this to trigger on mousemove for prior eventlistener event
elms.forEach(elm => (elm.style.pointerEvents = ''))
}

```
svg.addEventListener('mousemove', hitTest);
svg.addEventListener('touchmove', hitTest);
```

})();

Comment: Not sure to follow what you mean with this list of colors and new top element etc. Can't you simply store both colors as data attributes on your elements and then just check if they are in the list of hovered elements? https://jsfiddle.net/0k548cvf/1/

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful but hopefully this clarifies: Near the center of the svg.. hovering over Poly 1 would show red, Star would show orange, Gradient_Poly_1 would show yellow, etc...and pass down the array to all elements under the mouse/touchpoint.  When the mouse/touch is moved out of Poly 1, but over the Star as the top-most element under the mouse, Star becomes red and subsequent elements under Star at that mouse position (if any)  are passed the color array.

This fiddle also seems to get rid of pointerevents which seems necessary to obtain the list of IDs under the element?

Comment: No, no need for hacking with pointer-events, just loop the elements returned by elementsFromPoint

Comment: Thanks!
I also think I understand what your fiddle is doing.  It appears to apply the colors in order of the document (what is top-most in source code)... not in order of "top-most element" under the mouse/pointer/touch event.  So, only the Ellpse_2 turns red...  Instead, I am looking to make that *top-most element under the mouse red*
It doesn't appear to be as simple as reversing the color order in the array..  I also think this will require I reverse the order of the elementsFromPoint for the list view. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks - I think I figured out passing the color, but can't pass the list of IDs.  https://jsfiddle.net/mmmd81/3560qvj1/24/  Any help is appreciated.   Also, Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than "change back" every element in the whole SVG on mousemove?  There will be one with thousands of elements... so it will have to change each element thousands of times on each mouse move, right?

Comment: Of note, I am OK with this SVG being transparent until hovered... would just removing the background color until hover increase efficiency?